# Unable to locate element in Python Selenium but everything is right

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm getting this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="login_login"]"}
```

the html code is:

```
<input type="text" id="login_login" name="login_login" value="" class="medium" onchange="this.form.login_nojs.value='';" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
```

and my code is:

```
driver.get('url')
sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_name('login_login').send_keys(username)
```

I also tried finding the element by name and xpath but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong? The URL is: https://www.lernsax.de/wws/9.php#/wws/100001.php?sid=47956263649257394861937833783210Sdc791afc

Comment: if I `wget` that url and grep it, there is no `login_login` anywhere. Are you sure its really what you are looking for?

Comment: E.g. if you check `driver.page_source`, is `login_login` there?

Comment: if i inspect the above text field it is named login_login

Comment: So is the url you give in the question incorrect?

Comment: i think i figured it out. it is inside an ifrmae

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue at this site. It seems the `soup.page_source` is empty. There is some javascript code executed which seems to clear the page source (and then adds an iframe to display the content)?
`$('#body_inner').empty().......`

Comment: For me page is not opening. So from my point of view, its website issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the element is inside an IFRAME. In order for Selenium to see inside an IFRAME, you have to switch context to that IFRAME and then the element will be accessible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('url')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'main_frame')))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME('login_login'))).send_keys(username)
```

The [python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: I found a 1 second sleep between actions was needed. Example, after switching, after entering username and after entering password. Not an ideal solution however.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks... I updated the answer to use a wait for that first action after the switch

Comment: I would check that as I think it is visible but needs some other condition. That is why I had ugly 1 second waits. There probably is a better way but I didn't find it in my few minutes play. I found execute_script (I know - purists will curse) could populate that without a pause but only for username.